# PhoneGap resolveLocalFileSystemURL Issue (Error 5)

Tags: cordova, filesystems

I am using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) to build an iOS application and using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) to debug. So far so good.

I am trying to use the media-capture and file APIs to capture a video and get its base64 representation. I can get the video recorder to open, take a video, and return. The problem is I can not get resolveLocalFileSystemURL to open the given path. Every time it returns with an error code of 5 to which I can not seem to find a single answer as to what that means. This is running on a real device so it is not a problem with the emulator.

I have checked every post I could find via Google and Stack Overflow I have read blog posts and the comments within. Have been scratching my head for days on this one. Everyone who proposed an answer was either using Xcode-- as opposed to Build-- or the answer simply did not work for me. This is such a simple thing to have to do, I can not figure out where the problem could be...

Below is my code. Below that is the console output.

```
elements["media_video"].onclick = function(event) {
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
        function(files) {
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < files.length ; ++i ) {
                var file = files[i];
                var name = file.name;
                var path = file.fullPath;
                var type = file.type;
                var lastModifiedDate = file.lastModifiedDate;
                var size = file.size;
                console.log(0, name, path, type, lastModifiedDate, size);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                    console.log(3, event.target.result);
                };
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                    path,
                    function(entry) {
                        console.log(1, entry.name);
                        reader.readAsDataURL(entry);
                        // send base64 data to server
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log(2, error.code);
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        function(error) {},
        {
            limit:  1
        }
    );
};
```

> 0 "capturedvideo.MOV" "/private/var/mobile/Applications/[application
>   uuid]/tmp/capture/capturedvideo.MOV" "video/quicktime" 1409866447000
>   205788
>
> 2 5

**Edit 1**
I do not have a Mac on which to use Xcode which is why I choose a cloud-based service.

**Edit 2**
Testing on iOS v7.1.2.

Comment: Should you be calling  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL in reader.onloadend?

Comment: My understanding is that reader.onloadend() is called after the file has loaded. Thus I do not call reader.readAsDataURL() until I have FileReader() all setup.

I am pretty sure this is not my problem, however. The code does not even get that far, calling the resolveLocalFileSystemURL() error callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take `/private` off the initial path (on older iOS versions [<7], you need to take off the `/localhost` portion of the path).

For some reason iOS thinks you shouldn't be able to have access to any directory starting with `private` even if the full path eventually lands within your sandbox. Frustrating to debug, to say the least, but it is an easy fix once you know what to look for.

---

**Edited 8/5/2014 6:06:**

---

I just now noticed you also aren't supplying a URL scheme -- you need to have `file://` prepended to your path, otherwise you get this particular error. Your final path should look like this prior to calling `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/[application uuid]/tmp/capture/capturedvideo.MOV
```

Comment: Switching to
var path = file.fullPath.substr(8);
did not solve the issue. Same output (minus the change I made to reflect your suggestion).

Comment: I just noticed the lack of file:// in your path -- resolveFileSystemURL is resolving a URL, so it needs file:// prepended to your path.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. First wedding anniversary.

That nailed it! You, sir, are my new favorite random stranger. My sanity thanks you so much.

Feel like a bit of a dope for not realizing it was not a valid URL. Forest for the trees...

Comment: No prob & congrats on the anniversary! Also glad it worked! Believe me, I've hit my head on this several times (and the dent to prove it), including forgetting the schema or the fact that the capture plugin likes to return some funny URLs for iOS that don't work with the File API.

Comment: This can't still be the answer to this!?! I've encountered the same issue and sure it works if I replace '/private' with 'file://' for iOS but I feel like I'm going to get bitten by this somehow